# What am I doing incorrectly with the Boolean modifier? *Video attached*

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, transforms, workflow

I have two objects that are planes and when I attempt to apply the Boolean, the modifier simply does not work.

I have been racking my brain and searching the internet to try and figure out why the Boolean modifier is not working for me.

I have applied rotation, scale, and location.

I also was able to have the modifier work with two simple planes.

Any and all help is welcome, thank you!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wo0kxsovobzij0gBlMff8IOa41fKfwHA/view?usp=sharing

Edit
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F3Z020GwRJ8jEBpgRR_YtysTRJ_KOgFF/view?usp=sharing

Edit*
My scene is very basic, I haven't tweaked any settings. I am attempting to build a cleaning cart. The first photo is a reference image of what I am shooting for. The second photo shows my first draft of the cart and the new one I am working on.

[image: The cleaning cart reference.]

[image: My entire scene including my draft cart and the current one being worked on.]

Comment: Please don't make your questions depend exclusively links to understand the 
issue. Please use the [edit] option at the bottom of your question 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how 
you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help others 
understand your scene and settings.

Comment: can you show us your blend file?

Comment: @Chris I added the file and some images for ya!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the face orientation of your parts. Blue is ok, red is wrong.

Repair the face orientation and it will work.

you can check your (wrong) face orientation by tapping [image]

[image]